# how can i access web cam and capture images in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, flash, webcam, capture

I'm developing a web project and it need access client's web cam and capture images then store them on the server. And i found silverlight 4 can do this,,but the problem is my project runs on the .net 3.5 server machine (i can't change it) , so i cant use silverlight 4. Any one has idea about how to do this in asp.net? (It's ok with me flash plugings or anything) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here are some resources to help you do this:
http://weblogs.asp.net/nleghari/articles/webcam.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/webcamcsharp.aspx